# How to unfreeze excel column using python script

Tags: python, excel

How to unfreeze excel column using python script

`wb = load_workbook(excel_file)`
`ws = wb.active`
`ws.freeze_panes = None`
`wb.save(excel_file)`

Using above code unfreeze is happening, however If you open processed excel file, the below error is prompted

"we found a problem with some content in excel_file.xlsx. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes"

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below to avoid this error: "we found a problem with
some content in excel_file.xlsx. Do you want us to try to recover as
much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes"

##### ws - worksheet, wb - workbook

```
ws.sheet_view.selection = [ws.sheet_view.selection[0]] 
ws.sheet_view.selection[0].pane = 'topLeft'
wb.save(excel_file)
```